# Reversing a string in Python using a loop?

Tags: python, string, function, loops, reverse

I'm stuck at an exercise where I need to reverse a random string in a function using only a loop (for loop or while?).

I can not use `".join(reversed(string))` or `string[::-1]` methods here so it's a bit tricky.

My code looks something like this:

```
def reverse(text):
    while len(text) > 0:
        print text[(len(text)) - 1],
        del(text[(len(text)) - 1]
```

I use the `,` to print out every single letter in text on the same line!

I get invalid syntax on `del(text[(len(text)) - 1]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the string or print the characters in reverse order? Your title implies the former but your code seems to be trying to do the latter. If you want to reverse the string -- build it up and then *return* the reversed string. Let the calling code print it if it wants. Most functions shouldn't have `print` in them.

Comment: You could use a temp variable to build the reversed string instead of manipulating the original string

Comment: `del` modifies an object, but you cannot modify a string, you must create a new string instead. Try creating a new string with one character fewer: `text = text[:-1]`

Comment: @Duncan true enough -- but pointless. OP has no good reason for trying to make the string smaller in the course of building up the reverse.

Comment: i want to reverse the string, for example def reverse("abcd") should return "dcba"

Comment: @JohnColeman, his approach will work by deleting the end character from the string (except he should probably be building up the reversed string in a variable rather than printing a character at a time) but "save last character then remove last character from the string" is a perfectly valid way to reverse it.

Comment: @Duncan I wouldn't say that a quadratic algorithm for reversing a string is *perfectly* valid, although it is of course valid. Creating a copy of the string at each stage is expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use `del` on a string in python.
However this code works without del and will hopefully do the trick:

```
def reverse(text):
    a = ""
    for i in range(1, len(text) + 1):
        a += text[len(text) - i]
    return a

print(reverse("Hello World!")) # prints: !dlroW olleH
```

Comment: Ok i understand but i dont understand the len(text) + 1

Comment: Why do you use + 1 for i to iterate through?

Comment: @DanielBäck It's only there because python was missing the last letter of the reversed word. To fix this I just added one so that it would loop once more and add the final letter.

Comment: okay i see thank you this solved my problem!

Comment: Hi @DanielBäck if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: ok but i can only accept 1 solution right?

Comment: @DanielBäck Yes, only one.

Comment: reversed = ''";
for i in range(len('123')):
    reversed += '123'[(i+1)*-1]

Answer (score 7):

Python string is not mutable, so you can not use the `del` statement to remove characters in place. However you can build up a new string while looping through the original one:

```
def reverse(text):
    rev_text = ""
    for char in text:
        rev_text = char + rev_text
    return rev_text

reverse("hello")
# 'olleh'
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that a complete answer benefits OP as much as a hint would.

Comment: @JacobVlijm `s[::-1]` is the only answer that benefits someone not doing a homework assignment. In any event -- surely this must be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are immutable. You cannot use del on string.

```
text = 'abcde'
length = len(text)
text_rev = ""
while length>0:
   text_rev += text[length-1]
   length = length-1

print text_rev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah its cool to se you can also use a while loop for it,

Comment: This one seems easier than using the for loop

Comment: @Daniel Bäck You can upvote my solution if you like it. That helps some one who is looking for same kind of answer like you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt using a decorator and a for loop. Put everything in one file.

**Implementation details:**

```
def reverse(func):
    def reverse_engine(items):
        partial_items = []
        for item in items:
            partial_items = [item] + partial_items
        return func(partial_items)
    return reverse_engine
```

**Usage:**

Example 1:

```
@reverse
def echo_alphabets(word):
    return ''.join(word)

echo_alphabets('hello')
# olleh
```

Example 2:

```
@reverse
def echo_words(words):
    return words

echo_words([':)', '3.6.0', 'Python', 'Hello'])
# ['Hello', 'Python', '3.6.0', ':)']
```

Example 3:

```
@reverse
def reverse_and_square(numbers):
    return list(
        map(lambda number: number ** 2, numbers)
    )

reverse_and_square(range(1, 6))
# [25, 16, 9, 4, 1]
```