# What does rev = '' mean in this context. I get that rev means reverse but what does the '' mean?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    data = input()
    if data == 'Done' or data == 'done' or data == 'd':
        break
    rev = ''
    for ch in data:
        rev = ch + rev
    print(rev)
```

Comment: `''` is a string.

Comment: You mean, what this expression `rev = ''` actually do?

Comment: It creates a variable named `rev` and assigns it the value of an empty string.

Comment: You should try 1) removing it to see what happens and why it's needed, 2) `print(rev)` on every iteration to see what the for loop is doing (building the string one character at a time).

Comment: Related: [Reversing a string in Python using a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41322353/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code, it is correct the `rev` variable acts as reverse of the input.

given this example:

`data` is `'hello'`

We start the `rev` variable as an empty string `''` and we iterate the data string character by character (`ch`) and inside the loop we made this operation we prepend the character to the current `rev` variable:

So, with the `hello` example:

1st iteration: `rev` = `ch`(h) + `rev`('')  -> rev now is 'h'

2nd iteration: `rev` = `ch`(e) + `rev`('h')  -> rev now is 'eh'

3rd iteration: `rev` = `ch`(l) + `rev`('eh')  -> rev now is 'leh'

4th iteration: `rev` = `ch`(l) + `rev`('leh')  -> rev now is 'lleh'

5th iteration: `rev` = `ch`(o) + `rev`('lle')  -> rev now is 'olleh'